# How to write a program that fills from the keyboard a two-dimensional table of integers A [3][2]

Tags: c++, arrays, integer

I can only write a program that fills from the keyboard a one-dimensional table
need to learn how to make a two-dimensional table.  Here's the code that I'm trying to make work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int A[3][2];
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\n",A[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be like (x=the numbers I enter)

```
    x
    x
    x
    x
    x
    x
```

I want that to be like:

```
      x  x  x
      x  x  x
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your modified working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int A[2][3];
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: so the only thing i had to do was to add printf("\n"); ?? thx man

Comment: That, and observe the exchanged sizes of the dimensions (2 rows, each 3 elements). Multi-dimensional arrays in C are somewhat tricky. The index operator `[]` evaluates left-to-right: the first (inner) index operation yields one of the two rows.

Comment: Well, it is valuable to get C arrays straight. The declaration and semantics of multi-dimensional arrays are somewhat counter-intuitive. Multi-dimensional C arrays are arrays of arrays, i.e. each element is itself an array. Say, you have `int A[3]` and want have an array of two of *those* (as is the case here), i.e. you want a 2-D array with 2 rows, three ints each, you have to declare `int A[2][3]`. That is, the new, outermost  dimension is the innermost index. `A[0]` is the first of two 1-D arrays with 3 ints. `A[0][2]`, which could be written `(A[0])[2]`, is the first array's last element.

Comment: I'm puzzled about the 'exchanged sizes'.  The original question title used `A[3][3]` (misspelled); the code uses `A[3][2]` and uses it perfectly correctly.  Yes, you can also use `A[2][3]` (and your code uses that correctly), but that is a different array shape.  Only different — but your comment makes it appear that you think the reshaping is crucial for some reason.  If you think it is crucial, please elucidate.